# Wordpress IP changed

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Pls help me out.
I made a wordpress webpage in Google cloud platform.
Couple of days back I tried to link my domain with the webpage.

But as I am not an expert.
From day before yesterday, I am not been able to login neither my wordpress admin  page nor my webpage is opening.
And in Google cloud platform, wordpress url and site address changed and even the external IP..
But how to retrieve my previous IP and my previous work..
Anyhow I need to retrieve my work.
Kindly look into it.

My wordpress ip which is not working- 35.221.56.166

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As mentiones [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options), the VMs sometimes have maintenance which means that the intance can be restarted. If you didn't assign an static IP to the VM, the VM will have an ephemeral IP that is relased when the VM is restarted or stoped.

Having said that, the IP your VM had was released and you cannot recover it.

I suggest to [reserve an static IP for your VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) and use the new IP to connect to your VM, etc.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63442917/wordpress-website-is-down-after-google-cloud-vm-instance-restart) a similar question.